# Why does Dask fill in "foo" and 1 in my Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I've read in around 15 csv files:

```
df = dd.read_csv("gs://project/*.csv", blocksize=25e6,
                 storage_options={'token': fs.session.credentials})
```

Then I persisted the Dataframe (it uses 7.33 GB memory):

```
df = df.persist()
```

I set a new index because I want my group by on that field to be as efficient as possible:

```
df = df.set_index('column_a').persist()
```

Now I have 181 divisions and 180 partitions.
To try out how fast my group by was going I tried a custom apply function that just prints the Group Dataframe:

```
grouped_by_index = df.groupby('column_a').apply(lambda n: print(n)).compute()
```

That printed a Dataframe with correct columns but the values are either "1", "foo" or "True". Example:

```
column_b  column_c column_d  column_e  column_f  column_g  \
index                                                                   
a          foo           1      foo        1           1           1
```

I also get the warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data.
>   Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.   Before:
>   .apply(func)   After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for
>   dataframe result   or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))
>   for series result   """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, if you read the docs for `apply`, you will see that `meta=` is a parameter that you can pass, which tells Dask how to expect the output of the operation to look. This is necessary because `apply` can do very general things.

If you *don't* supply `meta=`, as in your case, than Dask will try to seed the operation with an example mini-dataframe containing 1 for any numerical columns and "foo" for text ones, just to see what the output will be like. Since in your `apply` you print (and don't actually return anything), you are seeing this seed.

As suggested by the documentation, you are always better off providing `meta=` when possible, and then a whole step in the process can be avoided.

Comment: When I provide meta data I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`. I define meta data like this: `meta = {'project': 'object', 'net': 'int64', 'no': 'object', 'v': 'int64', 'min': 'int64', 'avg': 'int64', 'associated': 'bool'}`.

Comment: I thought that ought to work, but you'd be best off providing a zero-length dataframe.

Comment: I defined meta like this: `meta=('visits', object)` and that did it trick, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah yes - it was the *output*  that you are defining, which is just a single set of `None` values (because you don't return anything from the lambda).

Comment: Even after specifying meta as "object" in case of apply function returning a dictionary, parameter values being passed is "foo" for empty cells. This doesn't seem to work correctly. Thanks